# Parse error: unexpected end of the file, can't find it

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

i'm trying to fix a error, i maked a little search and they send that was something because { or } not closed propely, but i can't find it.

The code is this one:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /movies.php on line 176**
the code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/258531c7a81517c47de5

Comment: If you use [indentation](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079), you may likely see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Line 167, close your else statement

```
<?php $active = get_option('widget_single'); if ($active == "true") {  dynamic_sidebar( 'Single Movie' );  } else { ?>
<?php $activar_ads = get_option('activar-anuncio-300-250'); }  if ($activar_ads == "true") ?>
```